# How Can We Hide One Tab Onclicking Of Another Tab Menu apps icon in Ionic 2?

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic2

I am developing an ionic 2 application and have multiple tabs in my application. I need to hide the top tab when clicking the bottom tabs menu icon.

- [My Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/yf4UI7RFFPSPgvnG0aUS?p=preview) for reference.

What I am looking for is, on clicking the bottom tab menu apps icon, the above tab need to be hidden.

In angularjs I can hide this field using `ng-hide` but I don't know how to hide this field in ionic 2.

**On clicking** `tab menu apps icon`:

```
<ion-tabs tabs-only>
    <ion-tab tabIcon="apps" [root]="tab3Root"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

**The above tab need to be hide**

```
<ion-tabs tabs-only2 tabbar>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="Tab 1" tabIcon="pulse"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" tabTitle="Tab 2" tabIcon="pulse"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

**My multiple tab elements:**

```
<ion-tabs tabs-only>
    <ion-tab tabIcon="apps" [root]="tab3Root"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>

<ion-tabs tabs-only2 tabbar>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="Tab 1" tabIcon="pulse"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" tabTitle="Tab 2" tabIcon="pulse"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

Please update the [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/yf4UI7RFFPSPgvnG0aUS?p=preview) If you have a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ionic2 is using Angular2 and you can use the [hidden] binding to hide based on click binding to any element you want. But remember the ion-tabs is also container for the tab pages, and not just some menu. Hiding it will hide the current tab page.

check [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/RETdhisDggyxLA7DLjdm?p=preview)

```
<ion-tabs tabs-only (click)="x()" >
    <ion-tab tabIcon="apps" [root]="tab3Root"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>

<ion-tabs tabs-only2 tabbar (click)="x()" [hidden]="hideTopTab" >
  <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="Tab 1" tabIcon="pulse"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" tabTitle="Tab 2" tabIcon="pulse"></ion-tab>

</ion-tabs>
```

and

```
  hideTopTab:boolean=false;
  x(){
    this.hideTopTab = true;
  }
```

Comment: @ n00b thanks for your valuable answer it's works perfectly... thanks